# Can IT Hit WebDAV also support SFTP or FTPS?

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I know it's a long shot, but we're using an older version of the server with custom logic to integrate with our app and it would be just swell if we could offer SFTP as well for customers that want to integrate via FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT Hit WebDAV Server does not support FTP/SFTP. We consider FTP to be outdated protocol.